# Android Facebook login, Graph user and Response is null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

possible duplicate: [Request.GraphUserCallback always return a null user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457137/request-graphusercallback-always-return-a-null-user)

---

I'm trying to call the Graph API after login (following this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph)

I log in successfully and even retrieve an access token from the session, so it's working.

But when I try to fetch data from graph user I always get a null user and a null response.

```
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            // Request user data and show the results
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Display the parsed user info
                        Log.i(TAG,buildUserInfoDisplay(user));
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Realised I made a stupid mistake. Just add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

as a child of  in your Manifest file.